# UserForm not allowing me to edit excels after running one button

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want a userForm as a tool to run process in steps meaning that the user would click one button,  something would happen, then the user would modify an excel and would click to another button from same userform.

Is something like this possible with userforms?

As soon as I run a button from the userform it freezes all the excel sheets open and I am only allowed to click another button in userform.

Comment: Set the Showmodal property of the form to False - but beware, when you do that, the calling program will proceed with any code after the form launches.